# When should std::move be used for built-in types?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Considering the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
    std::vector<int> myvector;
    int myint;

    std::cout << "Please enter some integers (enter 0 to end):\n";

    do {
        std::cin >> myint;
        myvector.push_back (myint);
    } while (myint);

    std::cout << "myvector stores " << int(myvector.size()) << " numbers.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Why wouldn't you use `std::vector<int>::push_back(int&&)`, so `myvector.push_back( std::move(myint) )`?

Comment: Because it means typing extra 11 characters for no benefit whatsoever. It neither helps nor hurts (except perhaps readability).

Comment: You really should spend some time reading the questions from the tags you used.

Comment: Integers have value semantics and they don't cost *more* to copy than they do to move. So I'd opt for the most readable/simple way of doing this  and just use `push_back`.

Comment: Apart from the fact that moving an `int` is pointless, the code reads the value of `myint` in the `while` condition. For types where moving _does_ do something useful, that might be a problem, because the value might be changed by the move.